# Calculate value for Handlebars template on-the-fly?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

Is there a way to provide a function to Handlebars that calculates the value when needed, instead of supplying all values up-front in the context?

For example, say I wanted to fill out any template with example data:

```
var exampleFunction = function (varName) {
    return "Example " + varName;
};
```

If I know ahead of time what variables a Handlebars template needs, I could use this function to assemble a context.  However, what I really want to do is:

```
var template = Handlebars.compile(templateString);
var html = template.fillFromFunction(exampleFunction);
```

Is this possible?  If not, then are there any other template engines that support it?

---

Bonus question: can this be made asynchronous, e.g.:

```
var template = Handlebars.compile('{{foo.bar}}');
var dataFunction = function (path, callback) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        callback("Async " + path);
    }, 100);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short version:

It's a hack, but I've got a workaround.

```
var oldNameLookup = handlebars.JavaScriptCompiler.prototype.nameLookup;
handlebars.JavaScriptCompiler.prototype.nameLookup = function (parent, name) {
    return '(typeof ' + parent + ' === "function" ? '
        + parent + '(' + JSON.stringify(name) + ') : '
        + oldNameLookup(parent, name) + ')';
}
```

Usage:

```
var template = handlebars.compile('{{foo}} {{bar}}');
var dataFunction = function (key) {
    return 'data:' + key;
};
console.log(template(dataFunction));
// Outputs: "data:foo data:bar"
```

### Sub-properties:

To enable sub-properties (e.g. `"{{foo.bar}}"`), we need a wrapper method:

```
function transformFunc(dataFunction) {
    return function (key) {
        if (typeof key !== 'string') {
            return dataFunction('');
        }
        var pointerKey = '/' + key.replace(/~/g, '~0').replace(/\//g, '~1');
        return transformFunc(function (path) {
            return dataFunction(pointerKey + path);
        });
    };
}
```

Usage:

```
var template = handlebars.compile('{{foo}} {{foo.bar}}');
var dataFunction = transformFunc(function (path) {
    // path is a JSON Pointer path
    return "data:" + path;
});
console.log(template(dataFunction));
// Outputs: "data:/foo data:/foo/bar"
```

If one wanted, I suppose `.compile()` and `.precompile()` could be modified so that `transformFunc()` was applied to any incoming function when templating.

### Explanation:

The hack includes altering the code-generation of Handlebars, but this [code comment](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/blob/master/lib/handlebars/compiler/javascript-compiler.js#L10-L11) implies this is sort of OK.  I tried finding a way to subclass, but couldn't see how to get [this](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/blob/master/lib/handlebars/compiler/compiler.js#L438) or [this](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/blob/master/lib/handlebars/compiler/compiler.js#L457) to use it.

#### Short version: override the [`nameLookup()` method](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/blob/master/lib/handlebars/compiler/javascript-compiler.js#L12-L33).

This method usually generates JavaScript code like `depth0.foo` or `(depth1 && depth1.bar)`.  We're extending it so the generated code first checks the `parent` to see if it's a function.

If it's a function, then it calls the function with the property name as the argument.  Otherwise, it returns the same value as previously.  For example, it will generate something like:

```
(typeof depth0 === "function" ? depth0("foo") : (depth0 && depth0.foo))
```

For simple variables (e.g. just `"{{foo}}"`) you can now just supply a function and it will be called with the variable names.

#### Enabling sub-properties

However, for nested properties (i.e. `"{{foo.bar.baz}}"`) we actually need our function to return *another* function, which can either return appropriate data or be called with another property name, depending which is needed.

So: if our transformed function is not given a string, then it is assumed we are at the end-point (we want the actual data, not a sub-property), so we just call through.

If our transformed function is given a string, then it's assumed to be a key, so another (transformed) function is return that calls back to the data function, prefixing the argument appropriately.

Comment: No bonus points for me, as this is not asynchronous.  I'll live, I guess.